# Convert HTML File to Pipe('|') Delimited Text file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have received a huge HTML table data and has to convert into pipe delimited text file with enclosing character as single quote (').
I'm looking for a shell script to do this.

Below is the sample html,

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><title>Data</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border=1>
<tr>
<td bgcolor=silver class='medium'>patientName</td>
<td bgcolor=silver class='medium'>Address</td>
<td bgcolor=silver class='medium'>Age</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>Sanju</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>My address, Pin:12345</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>1</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

Below is expected output in text file,

```
|'patientName'|'Address'|'Age'
|'Sanju'|'My address, Pin:12345'|'1'
```

I tried to do it manually using Notepad++ by,

1. Removed table, body and html tags
2. Replaced `<td bgcolor=silver class='medium'>` with |'
3. Replaced \r\n with '
4. Removed  and .

For smaller files, it worked for me. But, for large files, it is taking time and Notepad++ doesn't work.

Comment: Unless you know for sure that the HTML is always **exactly** formatted like this (for instance, that each `td` exactly occupies one line, and the attributes are always in this sequence), I would use an HTML parser to make your script more robust.

Comment: It is a off-topic concern, but a big concern anyway. Basically, in a period of every week, data leaks, ransomware gangs hold on medical data, you are handling very confidential and critical patient data sipped from a display format HTML, handled in a shell script that is meant to process linear character streams and system operation tasks rather than using a suitable language for structured data from a true data source. That's very concerning indeed. And you "received this big html data source of patient addresses", I hope you have good lawyers if you are having a leak from your system.

Comment: You'll probably need to do something with input that already contains `'`s or `foo'bar` will become `'foo'bar'` and probably mess up whatever you want to do with it afterwards.. Why do you want to output `|`s and `'`s instead of CSV with `,`s and `"`s that some kind of a standard and many tools can then read directly?

Comment: You don't REALLY want a `|` at the start of each output line do you? That'd just be a waste of a character and introduce a leading field containing nothing before that `|`.

Comment: @EdMorton We faced issues while loading the csv files as it contains commas and " in the data. "foo,bar", "foo"bar", and some data goes to next line. After loading these csv files using sql developer, data populated to wrong columns.

Comment: @LéaGris The given data is a sample one/dummy one and in my original data, there is no such columns or data. But, of course it is patient data. Thank you for the response and valuable points shared.

Comment: @SoorajPGeorge you're describing invalid CSV, just don't create invalid CSV. You can have the same problem with any separator but at least with CSV the way to handle that is well defined/understood, unlike with other separators, see [whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk) for more info on CSVs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** As has been pointed out in the comments, an HTML parser would be a much more robust tool for the job. And also, yikes! I just reread the question and realized that you could be handling rather sensitive data. All the more reason to do this properly.

---

To do this in the shell, we can use a couple of commands.

First, `sed`:

```
sed -n '/<table/,/<\/table>/p' input.html
```

This reads a file called `input.html` and removes anything that isn't between `<table>` tags.

We can then pass that to `awk`:

```
awk '
BEGIN { RS = "</tr>"; FS = "\n"; OFS = "" }
{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        gsub(/<[^>]*>/, "", $i);
        gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/, "", $i);
        if ($i != "") {
            printf("|'\''%s'\''", $i);
        }
    }
    if (NF > 0) {
        print "";
    }
}
' > output.txt
```

This removes the HTML tags from each row, then formats and prints each cell with a pipe and quotes. Finally, it adds a newline at the end of each row.

To put all of this together, create a script called `convert.sh` (or something similar) and add the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -n '/<table/,/<\/table>/p' input.html | awk '
BEGIN { RS = "</tr>"; FS = "\n"; OFS = "" }
{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        gsub(/<[^>]*>/, "", $i);
        gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/, "", $i);
        if ($i != "") {
            printf("|'\''%s'\''", $i);
        }
    }
    if (NF > 0) {
        print "";
    }
}
' > output.md
```

Make the file executable:

```
chmod +x convert.sh
```

Then run it like so:

```
./convert.sh
```

This assumes that you are running the script in same directory as `input.html`. If this is not the case, adjust the path accordingly.

It also assumes that the table has the format from your post (whereby attributes such as `class`or `bgcolor` are irrelevant):

```
<table border=1>
<tr>
  <td bgcolor=silver class='medium'>patientName</td>
  <td bgcolor=silver class='medium'>Address</td>
  <td bgcolor=silver class='medium'>Age</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class='normal' valign='top'>Sanju</td>
  <td class='normal' valign='top'>My address, Pin:12345</td>
  <td class='normal' valign='top'>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class='normal' valign='top'>Jim</td>
  <td class='normal' valign='top'>München</td>
  <td class='normal' valign='top'>2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Running the script against this gives us:

```
|'patientName'|'Address'|'Age'
|'Sanju'|'My address, Pin:12345'|'1'
|'Jim'|'München'|'2'
```

Hopefully that does what you want, but if not the script can be revised to take account of any deviations.

As a final note, consider using (or at least be aware of) semantic markup for your tables (e.g. `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, `<tfoot>`). See [here](https://web.dev/learn/html/tables/).

---

**Update**

Updated script to take account of line breaks:

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -n '/<table/,/<\/table>/p' input.html | awk '
BEGIN { RS = "</tr>"; FS = "<td[^>]*>"; OFS = "" }
{
  if (NF > 1) {
    printf("|");
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
      gsub(/<[^>]*>/, "", $i);
      gsub(/\n/, " ", $i);
      gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/, "", $i);
      printf("'"'"%s"'"'", $i);
      if (i < NF) {
        printf("|");
      }
    }
    print "";
  }
}
' > output.txt
```

Comment: Also, parsing HTML with improper tools is a very bad idea. Parsing HTML is a very bad idea in general because HTML is a display structure that has very permissive syntax and use nested elements. Awk, sed and Regexes in general are meant to deal with character streams and not nested tag and attributes. Even XML which is for Data what HTML is for display would be borderline not appropriate in a shell, even using `xmlstarlet`.

Comment: Agreed. Ideally, I would use something like Ruby & Nokigiri for this, as it is way more robust.

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk or similar for multi-char RS.

Comment: @JamesHibbard Thank you for the code and explanation. I have tried this code and it is worked perfectly except when the address has two lines. I tried, </td> as FS instead of \n and not worked. Any suggestion on this issue ?

Comment: Can you provide some sample HTML for an address with two lines. That is to say, how is the second line created ? With a `<br>` tag? Or a line break in the code?

Comment: @JamesHibbard There is no <br> tag. Line break is there and the second address line goes to new line and end with </td>

Comment: @SoorajPGeorge: I updated the script to take line breaks in the HTML into account. Does that now do what you want?

Comment: @JamesHibbard: It worked perfectly! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F'>|<' '
   /<tr>/,/<\/tr>/ {
      if(NF==5) printf "|\47%s\47", $3
   } 
   /<\/tr>/{printf "\n"}
' file
|'patientName'|'Address'|'Age'
|'Sanju'|'My address, Pin:12345'|'1'
```

Answer (score 1):

If your input always looks exactly like you show in your example then using GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    RS  = "</?tr[^>]*>"
    FS  = "</?td[^>]*>"
    OFS = "|"
    qt  = "\047"
}
(NR%2) == 0 {
    for ( i=2; i<NF; i+=2 ) {
        gsub(qt,"&&",$i)   # one way to handle embedded quotes
        out = (i>2 ? out OFS : "") qt $i qt
    }
    print out
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
'patientName'|'Address'|'Age'
'Sanju'|'My address, Pin:12345'|'1'
```

If we change `Sanju` to `Peter O'Toole` in your sample input file then we can see how the script handles embedded quotes by doubling then as required by the CSV standard, [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180):

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
'patientName'|'Address'|'Age'
'Peter O''Toole'|'My address, Pin:12345'|'1'
```

Change `(i>2 ? out OFS : "") qt $i qt` to `(i>2 ? out : "") OFS qt $i qt` if you really want a `|` at the start of each output line.

If you decide you want to produce CSV instead of your current format just change the values of `OFS` and `qt`:

```
    OFS = ","
    qt  = "\""
```

Like all answers that don't use an HTML parser, it is fragile.